# Need to check trigger perfomance

Tags: apex, trigger, code, after-trigger

I have created one trigger which checking if account owner and associated contact owner is same or not.Its giving me output correct.but when i am updating account using dataloader then its looping in contact loop many time.
Suppose i have updated 4 accounts and each account having 2 contact then in my trigger for each account -8 times contact loop is running.

```
trigger TimepassTrigger on Account (before insert,before update,before delete,after insert,after update) {
    If(trigger.isbefore  && (trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate)){
        Map<id,account> accountMap=new map<id,account>();
        for(account acc:trigger.new){
            accountmap.put(acc.id,acc);
        }
        List<contact> conlist=new list<contact>([select id,AccountId,ownerid,lastname from contact where accountid in:accountmap.keySet()]);
        for(account ac:accountmap.values()){
            for(contact con:conlist){
                if(accountmap.containsKey(con.AccountId) && con.OwnerId==accountmap.get(ac.id).ownerid){          
                    con.Description='Yes the Owner of the account and contact are same';
                }
                else
                    con.Description='No the Owner of the account and contact are not same';
            }
        }
        update conlist;
    }
}
```

Please suggest. See logs

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you only need to do this after update or after undelete. There will never be a contact available in an insert trigger, as it is a child record, and no child can exist before its parent.

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUndelete)) {
```

Second, what you really want is a map that holds lists of contacts:

```
Map<Id, List<Contact>> contacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
Contact[] updates = new Contact[0];
for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    contacts.put(record.Id, new Contact[0]);
}
for(Contact record: [SELECT AccountId, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :Trigger.new]) {
    contacts.get(record.AccountId).add(record);
    updates.add(record);
}
for(Account accRecord: Trigger.new) {
    for(Contact conRecord: contacts.get(accRecord.Id)) {
        if(conRecord.OwnerId==accRecord.OwnerId){          
            conRecord.Description='Yes the Owner of the account and contact are same';
        } else {
            con.Description='No the Owner of the account and contact are not same';
        }
    }
}
update updates;
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick response.Its working perfectly..Can you please explain me Contact[] updates = new Contact[0]; why we took 0 here.

Comment: Please also let me know where i can find the trigger examples to learn the trigger in advance.thanks

Comment: @sam `new Contact[0]` is the same as `new List<Contact>()`, but less typing. It says "create a new List of Contact type with 0 elements". You'll find examples of triggers like this here on SFSE and all over the web. Try going to the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) to learn more.